# How to clean up a messy git history?

Tags: git, version-control, merge, rebase, revision-history

I have a git project with a messy history, where branches with the same commits and different commit ids were merged and would like to clean it up.

What happened:

- normal git workflow.
- then I saw some older commits having the wrong author information (missing user.name setting) and rebased it.
- `git push --force`. (bad idea!)
- the next user merged his branch with his new commit into this branch. (I should have told everyone to do a fresh clone)
- I did not see the problem, and we continued to commit like normal. Some feature- and release-branches were used after the merge

The result:

There is a long timeline of commits on two different branches, which are absolutely identical and only differ, because their parent hash is different. It's not only unclean, but makes it harder to work with old commits (I guess git bisect would be a total mess) and the tree now still contains the bogus commits, which should have been rebased, too.

How can this be cleaned up, assuming that now everyone participating will NOT merge an old tree again?

Comment: Maybe `rebase -i` branchA against branchB taking out the duplicates?

Comment: I only know ``rebase -i`` with a linear history, how do i rebase two branches at the same time?

Comment: If the commit contents are identical on both branches, why not just abandon one of them?  Are there merges recorded between them, or what?

Comment: @allo: `git checkout branch_a`, `git rebase -i branch_b`, remove all duplicates by hand, then merge if needed.

Comment: @jthill: I assume OP's branches *do* have some commits that are only on either one. However, they can be `cherry-pick`ed. @allo: consider `git checkout branch_a`, `git cherry-picka sha1` where `sha1` is the hash of the commits on `branch_b` you want to keep.

Comment: It is really not too easy. In between there are normal merges from different users and some release branches with a few non-master commits before the release tag. Cherry picking would fix the parallel line, but each branch which is on both lines (and merged at both lines) can make trouble, the branches after the two parallel branches may be a problem as well. It would need to be some cherry-picking at the point right before the merge of the two big branches, until everything is right. Seems like a complicated task.

Comment: @allo It likely is a complicated task, you'll probably need a lot of handwork if you really want to carry out this.

The --preserve-merges option of rebase might help in some passage, but keep in mind that even with that rebase doesn't move either the references (the branches other than the one you rebase and the tags keep pointing to the old commits) or the notes (the notes remain attached to the old commits). You'll have to adjust these manually (I heard of an extension that corrected some of this but I can't find it anymore).

Comment: @Allo 
Of course most of all you need to be sure that everyone agrees to stop using the old history and rebase their branches over the new history.

Comment: The first task would be: detach the wrong history from the first wrong merge. So that the merge-commit gets a normal commit with just one parent. This could already fix a lot. Maybe i need to rebase / cherry-pick a few commits from the detached branch into the other one, but that's no big deal if the detaching works.

Comment: @allo Consider git replace as well, in your situation it might be the right choice